# Why is the star before some menus in Info are red?

Tags: info

There is one star (*) before every menu in Emacs info.  Some of them are red, I am wondering why they are red and what does the red means?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC the red highlight was introduced to help you count entries so you can jump directly to menu entries by number (the red stars correspond to entries 3, 6, and 9 respectively).

I've never made use of that feature, so I'm not sure how valuable it is.

Comment: I have never even noticed this. It does seem of limited value, but if the stars were replaced by menu numbers (at least the first 9), that would be useful!

Comment: @Tyler I use it and find it really usefull. Once used to it, finding an entry number is very immediate,  no need to think or count (at least for entries <10, those you can select with a one digit key).  Plus, this is very light on the eye (I suspect I would find numbered entries to add visual noise).

Comment: @JeanPierre ok, I'm converted. Now that I know what the stars mean, it is actually pretty handy!

Answer (score 3):

You can *ask Emacs*.

Emacs provides the ***Info* manual** as the first manual you see when you use command `info` (**`C-h i`**). It is a short manual that tells you all about using manuals with Info, the documentation browser built into Emacs.

Click its name to open that manual, then type **`i`** to check Index entries. (`i` is your friend in Info.)

You are interested in information about Info *menus*, so type `menu`, then `TAB` at the prompt from `i`.

That shows only a single completion of your input "`menu`": `menus in an Info document`. Hitting `RET` takes you to that node (page) of the manual, where you can read about Info menus in general.

Well ... tough luck.  This is a case where the manual's Index didn't help as much as it should have.

In fact, there *is* a node of the manual that tells you what you are asking.  But it is not indexed with an entry that *starts* with `menu`, so `i` doesn't find it.

That is, `i` doesn't find it if completion is the default sort, which does not do *substring matching*.  If you change option **`completion-styles`** so that your search pattern can match a substring of an index entry (or if you use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) or something similar) then -- *Bingo!* -- you see these other index entries as choices:

```
   Info-nth-menu-item 
   select N’th menu item
```

Admittedly, they don't scream **"menu item with a red star"**, but they do sound related, and they are.  Either of them takes you to node "**`1` to `9` choose a menu subtopic by its number**".  And there you see this:

> If your display supports multiple fonts, colors or underlining, and
>   you are using Emacs’s Info mode to read Info files, *the third, sixth and
>   ninth menu items have a **`*`** that stands out*, either in color or in some
>   other attribute, such as underline; this *makes it easy to see at a
>   glance which number to use for an item*.

And there you have it.

---

(FYI: I just filed Emacs [bug #26236](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26236) for this.)